Report with a child object as the primary object, rows grouped by field in parent object
Problem looks like this.
Every record in Object B has a relationship with a single record of Object A. (A records can have any number of B records associated with them.)
When I create a custom report type with B as the primary object and then A as the related object, if I try to use fields from object A, they are empty on the report, even if they are not empty on the record itself.
I think the issue has to do with B being a child(?) of A. But I dont know how to resolve that. If I try to make the report with A as the primary object, several records from B get filtered out if I use any filtering whatsoever.
